# Find MongoDB Records That Have Field Date < Date.now()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have Robomongo app linked up to MongoDB. When I run:

```
db.getCollection('bookings').find({"date" : { $lte : new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>")}})
```

I find the booking records with a date field that is before the current date + time.

However, when I try to do something similar inside my Node app using Mongoose, I get the following error:

```
{ MongooseError: Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" at path "date"
    at CastError (/Users/jack/Sites/view-bookings/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:26:11)
    at SchemaDate.cast (/Users/jack/Sites/view-bookings/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:221:13)
    at SchemaDate.handleSingle (/Users/jack/Sites/view-bookings/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:256:15)
    at SchemaDate.castForQuery (/Users/jack/Sites/view-bookings/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/date.js:289:18)
```

This is my current code:

```
router.get('/past', function(req, res) {
  //retrieve all bookings from Monogo
  mongoose.model('Booking').find({"date" : { $lte : new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>")}}, function (err, bookings) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } else {
            //respond to both HTML and JSON. JSON responses require 'Accept: application/json;' in the Request Header
            res.format({
                //HTML response will render the index.jade file in the views/bookings folder. We are also setting "bookings" to be an accessible variable in our jade view
              html: function(){
                  res.render('bookings/index', {
                        title: 'All my Bookings',
                        "bookings" : bookings
                    });
              },
              //JSON response will show all bookings in JSON format
              json: function(){
                  res.json(bookings);
              }
          });
        }
  });
});
```

First time using Mongoose so apologies if this is easy.

Comment: Have you tried `find({"date" : { $lte : new Date()}}, ...`?

Comment: Hint: Hit F12, got to the developers console and write `var test = new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>")`...then write `test` and it's going to show your something like this `[date] Invalid Date[date] Invalid Date`